# Is it possible to deploy Keycloak service on GCP's CloudRun?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

I'm trying to deploy a keycloak service on **Cloud Run** using a Postgres database on **Cloud SQL**. The dockefile I'm using looks as follows:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest

ENV DB_VENDOR postgres
ENV DB_ADDR <IP_ADDRESS>
ENV DB_DATABASE <DB_NAME>
ENV DB_SCHEMA public
ENV DB_USER postgres
ENV DB_PASSWORD postgres
ENV KEYCLOAK_USER admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD admin
ENV PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING true
ENV PORT 8080 
EXPOSE ${PORT}
```

Running this file on my localhost (via docker-compose) runs smoothly without issues, however, once I deploy it using GCP SDK it points to the following issue that I've been unable to fix. Does anyone have come to an issue like this one?

```sh
ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

[UPDATE]

After reviewing the logs I realized that I was having an error connecting to my Postgres database. However, even using two CPUs and 4Gi memory, the deployed service seems to be very slow in response when comparing with the same configuration deployed on App Engine.

Comment: First Approach in resolving this error would be to check cloud run logs..Can You tell the errors which you are seeing in the logs accordingly the solution can be provided on the basis of the error shown.

Comment: @DivyaniYadav I've just updated my question, looks like I'm having a high latency issue.

Comment: Hi, did you set any additional envs? I'm getting 404 when opening deplyed URL.